# See if ContentEditable div has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, contenteditable

I'm attempting to check whether or not a contenteditable div has focus, but I'm having some trouble.  Here's my code so far:

```
if ($("#journal-content:focus")) {
    alert("Has Focus");
} else {
    alert("Doesn't Have Focus");
}
```

The problem is, it's always returning "Has focus" even when it doesn't.  What's the best way to go about doing this?

**Update:** The reason for doing this is to see whether or not the cursor is in the desired location *before* inserting the new element. Otherwise, if the last place the user clicked was in the header, then when I restore the selection with Rangy and replace it with a new element, it ends up in the header.  I need a way to find out if the contenteditable div is focused/has the cursor in it, so if not, I'll simply append the element I'm inserting at the end.

**Update 2:** Here's a JSFiddle illustrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2NHrM/

Comment: Check out my update under Or:

Comment: I've updated the Fiddle using @iambriansreed's answer below so that it works.

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
if ($("#journal-content").is(":focus")) {
    alert("Has Focus");
} else {
    alert("Doesn't Have Focus");
}
```

Or:

```
window.contenteditable_focused = false;

$("#journal-content").focus(function() {
    //alert("Has Focus");
    contenteditable_focused = true;
});
$("#journal-content").blur(function() {
    //alert("Doesn't Have Focus");        
    contenteditable_focused = false;
});
```

Check for `contenteditable_focused` before executing your script.

Or:

```
if ($( document.activeElement ).is("#journal-content")) {
    alert("Has Focus");
} else {
    alert("Doesn't Have Focus");
}
```

Comment: ...but it does.  Right afterwards i'm using Rangy to save the selection, which works just fine.

Comment: The problem is, by the time the button is clicked the element has already lost focus.

Answer (score 5):

What about this?:

```
if (document.activeElement.isContentEditable) {
...
}
```

I don't know how well browser support for this is but at least Chrome and Firefox support it.

Comment: Most reliable answer for me, thanks. Most other didn't work

Answer (score 5):

**For pure JavaScript when you have multiple contenteditable elements:**

Check `document.activeElement.id` or `document.activeElement.isContentEditable`.

**Example:**

```js
function isFocused() {
  if (document.activeElement.id === "journal-content") {
    alert("Focused!");
  } else {
    alert("Not focused :(");
  }
}
```

```css
#journal-content {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#not-journal-content {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="journal-content" contenteditable="true" onclick="isFocused()">Journal Content</div>
<div id="not-journal-content" contenteditable="true" onclick="isFocused()">Not Journal Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if ($("#journal-content").is(":focus")) {
...
```

Maybe if you'll tell us what are you trying to achieve we'll be of a more help.
Meanwhile, you can have a read here: http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/.

Comment: Alrighty, updated my original post with an explanation of what I'm attempting to do. ( I tried yours and it doesn't seem to work).

Comment: If you follow the link I've posted you'll see this:
_If you are looking for the currently focused element, $( document.activeElement ) will retrieve it without having to search the whole DOM tree._